# Can you explain me the JS code ? How its working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, closures

```
console.log([1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5].map((acc = 0 , num => acc += num)));
// output : [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

I know closure has been applied here to this code but don't know how it's working, step by step - I want to visualize that.

We know the map has this Signature:

```
array.map(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

With this can anyone explain the code above to me?

Comment: This is only valid if you're not in strict mode, or have already declared `acc` somewhere. This is using the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), in combination with the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to first  assisgn a value to `acc` and then pass the callback to `map`.

Comment: @pilchard its working fine friend.Please check it again
https://jsfiddle.net/peyv13un/

Comment: @pilchard you're mistaken, that is valid javascript making use of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: @Samathingamajig I elaborated on my statement. It isn't valid in strict mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically creating a closure, but the key part is that this is declaring a global variable `acc` (unless `acc` already exists in the current scope), initializing it with the value `0`, then using that inside the anonymous arrow function. By using the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), it's done inline.

```js
console.log([1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5].map((acc = 0 , num => acc += num)));
// output : [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

console.log(acc, window.acc); // acc exists globally
```

It's equivalent to this:

```js
acc = 0;
console.log([1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5].map(num => acc += num));
// output : [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

console.log(acc, window.acc); // acc exists globally
```

Note that in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), unless you've declared the variable before, the program will fail.

```js
"use strict";

console.log([1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5].map((acc = 0 , num => acc += num)));
// output : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: acc

console.log(acc, window.acc); // acc doesn't exist because program exits
```

```js
"use strict";

let acc;

console.log([1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5].map((acc = 0 , num => acc += num)));
// output : [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

console.log(acc, window.acc); // acc doesn't exist globally, but it does locally
```

Comment: It's either a closure or global, not both. If you want a closure in this instance then use an IIFE `console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(((acc = 0)=> (num) => (acc += num))()));`

Comment: @pilchard globals are included in a closure [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) "In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time."  "Every closure has three scopes: 1. Local scope (Own scope) 2. Enclosing scope (can be block, function, or module scope) 3. Global scope"

Comment: I suppose in the sense that acc will always be initilialized with the same starting value that's true, though it leaves it available in the global scope afterwards. That's fair.

Comment: So we can say that 'acc' has been maintained as a global variable as a result separate closures can access the same 'acc' unlike a real closure which usually have different lexical scopes. @Samathingamajig